# Date Format in the label

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I'm creating a very simple app, but now I'm stalled.

---

I would like to put in the UICollectionViewCell a UILabel (with storybord) and I would like to configure the lable, to run this command

```
        format.dateFormat = "EEEE dd MMMM"
```

I'm sure it's very simple but I'm not in a position to find the solution

thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not using SwiftUI.

You need to set up some object to serve as the data source for your collection view. Typically that's your view controller.

Inside the data source, you need to implement the method `cellForItem(at:)`.

In that method you'll dequeue a collection view cell and install the data into it.

Creating a date formatter is a fairly expensive operation, so I'd suggest defining a lazy var in your view controller to hold your date formatter.

```
lazy var formatter: DateFormatter = {
   let aFormatter = DateFormatter()
   aFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE dd MMMM"
   return aFormatter
}
```

Then in your cellForItem(at:), you'd dequeue a cell of the correct type:

```
func cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell? {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCellType else {
       fatalError("Splat!") 
     }
    cell.dateLabel = aFormatter.string(for: model[indexPath.row].date
}
```

For the above to work you'll need to set up a storyboard with a prototype cell with a cell identifier, and set up a collection view subclass MyCellType that has an outlet dateLabel.

If none of this makes any sense to you then you need to slow down and study collection views, data sources, storyboards, prototype cells, etc. It's quite a bit to learn about. (In other words **no**, it's not very simple.)